# Vue, prepopulating a multiselect value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently using a Vue multiselect by loading it with options from an axios return object into `taskLocations`:

```
        <multiselect 
            v-model="taskLocations" 
            :options="locationOptions" 
            :multiple="true" 
            placeholder="Please choose at least one location" 
            label="name" 
            track-by="id">
        </multiselect>
```

This works perfectly but I'm now loading the page with another response that I've assigned to `editDetails[]` in my data return, and while that works in order to dump data for confirmation, I can't figure out how to keep the multiselect list of options from `taskLocations` while also preopopulaitng the value for the multiselect with `editDetail.location`

```
        <multiselect 
            v-for="editDetail in editDetails"
            v-model="taskLocations" 
            :options="locationOptions" 
            :multiple="true" 
            placeholder="Please choose at least one location" 
            label="name" 
            track-by="id">
        </multiselect>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: are you using this package only? https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-props. If yes, try passing location value in :value prop.

Comment: Yes I am. So I just add :value to the multiselect and I don't have to add that anywhere else?

Comment: Ya, that should work.

Comment: Isn't it just `v-model="editDetail.location"`? I'm not really clear what *'keep the multiselect list of options from `taskLocations`'* means.